# IntelliJ IDEA + arquillian test coverage

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage, jboss-arquillian, intellij-14

Is there any possibility to see code coverage by arquillian tests in IntelliJ IDEA?
Like on this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEsRk.png

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible. But you can write a plugin for that ;)